# Write two different SQL statements to generate the following tables

Tags: mysql, database, create-table

I have this question: `driver` and `car` are two tables in the insurance database system. Using MySQL server, the following SQL statements were executed, in the order as shown below, to implement `driver` and `car` tables with data.

```
CREATE TABLE driver 
(
    driverID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    cityAddress VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE car 
(
    plateID CHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    model VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    driverID INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO driver VALUES ('111', 'Ahmad', 'Madaba'); 
INSERT INTO driver VALUES ('222', 'Mazen', 'Zarqa');

INSERT INTO car VALUES ('111aaa', 'Toyota', '222');
INSERT INTO car VALUES ('222bbb', 'Nissan', '111');
INSERT INTO car VALUES ('333ccc', 'Mitsubishi', '111');
```

on the above information, answer the following 4 questions:

I have provided a screenshot for the 4 questions; I wrote only one statement for each question, I did not know how to write a second statement - can you help me?

[image: part2 and part3]

[image: part1]

[image: part4]

Answer (score 0):

I am just using the first question as example but for me:

```
SELECT c.driverID, name, cityAddress, plateID, model, d.driverId FROM driver d, car c WHERE d.driverID = c.driverID;
SELECT d.driverID, name, cityAddress, plateID, model, c.driverId FROM driver d, car c WHERE c.driverID = d.driverID;
```

can be considered as two different statements. If it cannot be considered as t, you may add an `ORDER BY` close.